# Saving another type to an attribute of an entity to core data?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

```
cell.textLabel.text = operationEnt.operationNaam;
```

on this line of code I get the error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString operationNaam]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6bce400'
```

But operationNaam is an attribute defined as a String. So I'm wondering, where is my mistake.
This is when I try to fill my cells of my TableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception means that the message `operationNaam` is being sent to a NSString object, and NSString does not recognize that message selector.

This means that your `operationEnt` object has somehow become a NSString during runtime.

Possibly, you did this...

```
operationEnt = someString;
```

when you meant this...

```
operationEnt.operationNaam = someString;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you either have memory management issues or misunderstand Objective-C's property accessor syntax.o `operationEnt` keeps becoming an NSString which doesn't respond to that particular property getter message, hence the crash. (Watch out for overreleases!)

Comment: You're right, 
my array was filled with strings, instead of Operation objects.